# Graph theory Euler graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph wheres $deg (v) =p >1$ for all $v \in V$ and also $|V|=2p+1    ,$  I need to show that G and his Complement graph are Euler graphs....
$$$$
I think that i manage to prove that it has Hamilton path but no more progress so far... thank you for help or any direction to how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every connected grapgh $G$ is Eulerian grapg iff for every vertex $v\in V_G$, $deg(v)$ is even. Suppose $G$ is not connected, because for every $v\in V_g$, $deg(v)=p$, therefore every componnet of $G$ has at least $p+1$ vertecis, and that means $V_G>2p+1$ which leads to contradiction, so $G$ is connected. Also $\sum_{v\in V_G}deg(v)=p(2p+1)=2E$, therefore $p$ is even, so $G$ is Eulerian. The same arguments works for $\bar G$, because for every $v\in V_{\bar G}$, $deg(v)=2p-p=p$.

Comment: if it has atleast $p+1$ dosent it mean that $V_G >p+1$ ? and not what you wrote?

Comment: @user152711: I said suppose $G$ is not connected, then it has at least two compnnets and everycomponnent has size at least $p+1$, therefore we should have $V_G>2p+1$

Comment: why does the complement  $deg(v)=2p-p$ ? and also why is it connected?

Comment: If $deg(v)=k$ in $G$, then $deg(v)=|V_G|-1-k$ in $\bar G$, so in this problem $deg(v)=2p-p=p$. Because $\bar G$ has $2p+1$ vertices and every $v\in V_{\bar G}$ has degree $p$, then the same arguments works here to prove $\bar G$ is Eulerian.